# Weekly Report in c# using ms access

Tags: c#, ms-access

```
            string query = "select * from OrderDataListTable RIGHT JOIN OrderDataTable ON OrderDataTable.OrderNo = OrderDataListTable.OrderNo WHERE MONTH(`DATETIME`) = "+month+"   ";

            command.CommandText = query;

            reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            counter = 0;
            dataGridView2.Rows.Clear();
            while (reader.Read())
            {

                dataGridView2.Rows.Add();
                dataGridView2.Rows[counter].Cells["productName"].Value = reader["ProductName"].ToString();
                dataGridView2.Rows[counter].Cells["quantity"].Value = reader["Quantity"].ToString();
                counter++;

            }
            conn5.Close();
       }
```

This is my code for the monthly format, is there a syntax for weekly? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It depends how you want to define the week. 
When you have the date for Monday and the date for Sunday, just use

```
..."WHERE DATETIME BETWEEN #"+ dateOfMonday + "# AND #" + dateOfSunday + "#   "
```

See also http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_between.asp
...From headline *BETWEEN Operator with Date Value Example*

Be careful to format the date Access-SQL-suitable.

Another solution would be to convert the date to weeknumbers. There are some articles on the web about that. I will not explain that further, becauseI have not used it by myself.

Answer (score 0):

As for the month, find the dates of the week:

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Parse(textBox2.Text);
// Find Monday of the week of textBox2.
DateTime first = date.AddDays(-(date.DayOfWeek - DayOfWeek.Monday + 7) % 7);
// Find Sunday of the week of textBox2.
DateTime last = date.AddDays((DayOfWeek.Sunday - date.DayOfWeek + 7) % 7);

string startDate = first.ToString("yyyy'/'MM'/'dd");
string endDate = last.ToString("yyyy'/'MM'/'dd");
```

and then again:

```
string query = "select * from OrderDataListTable where [DATETIME] between #" + startDate + "# and #" + endDate + "#";
```